# Substituir o valor de um input e manter o valor anterior

Tags: javascript, html, input, mask

Preciso de um `input[type="text"]`, em que o usuário escreva qualquer coisa ("abc", por exemplo), mas no visual apareça outros símbolos, mas mantendo o valor anterior quando pego pelo JavaScript ou enviado num `form` (como num `input[type="password"]`).

Seria isso possível?

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: O que voce tentou ate agora? Coloque o codigo para vermos e te falarmos o que voce precisa ajustar ou corrigir

Answer (score 1):

O mais simples possível é usar CSS `-webkit-text-security`

Pode usar os valores `none`, `square`, `circle` ou `disc`.

Exemplo abaixo usando `circle`:

```js
    function Foo() {
     frm = document.getElementById("frm");
     document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = frm["foo"].value;
     //console.log(frm["foo"].value);
    }
```

```css
input.foo { -webkit-text-security: circle; }
```

```html
    <form id="frm" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="foo" class="foo" size="15">
    <input type="button" value="clique para ver o texto real" onclick="Foo();">
    </form>
    
    <br><div id="bar"></div>
```

A parte em JavaScript é apenas para testes com finalidade didática, para exibir o texto real.

Answer (score 0):

Em javascript, algo manual é substituir os caracter por outros radômicamente a medida que o usuário digita e armazenar o valor original. Poderia ser mais ou menos como:

```js
var textoOriginal = '';
var entrada = document.getElementById("entrada");

function embaralhar(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (x !== 8) { 
    textoOriginal += entrada.value.substr(entrada.value.length - 1);

    entrada.value = entrada.value.replaceAt(entrada.value.length -1, randomico());
  }
};

function exibir() {
  document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = textoOriginal;
};

function limpar() {
  textoOriginal = '';
  document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("entrada").value = '';
};

function randomico() {
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

}

String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index + character.length);
}
```

```html
<input id="entrada" type="text" onkeypress="embaralhar(event)" />
<label id="texto">
  <br/>
  <br/>
<button id="exibir" onClick="exibir()">Exibir Original
<button id="limpar" onClick="limpar()">Limpar</button>
```

É um exemplo. Para um caso real, é importante validar se o usuário apaga algum valor, apaga por meio de seleção, etc.